# Sorting columns with hierarchy and additional column for sorting

Tags: postgresql, sorting, hierarchical-data

I have following structure:

```
id,
name,
parent_id,
order_by
```

and entries:

```
 id |    name   | parent_id | order_by 
----+-----------+-----------+----------
  8 | Cat 1     |           |        1
  7 | Cat 2     |           |        2
  5 | Cat 3     |           |        3
 15 | Cat 1.1   |         8 |        1
 17 | Cat 1.2   |        15 |        2
 16 | Cat 2.1   |         8 |        1
 20 | Cat 1.2.1 |        17 |        1
```

And I wanna output:

```
 id |    name   | parent_id | order_by 
----+-----------+-----------+----------
  8 | Cat 1     |           |        1
 15 | Cat 1.1   |         8 |        1
 17 | Cat 1.2   |         8 |        2
 20 | Cat 1.2.1 |        17 |        1
  7 | Cat 2     |           |        2
 16 | Cat 2.1   |         7 |        1
  5 | Cat 3     |           |        3
```

So sort main entries (without parent_id) using `order_by` column and sort in children using `order_by` column for children in one level.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the input data you have provided - in the first table the parent_id of Cat1.2 is 15 and in the second it's 8. The same goes for Cat2.1 - in the first table it's 8, in the second it's 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I assume that the for `id` = 16 the `parent_id` should be **7**, not 8

---

You need a recursive query to go through the whole tree. You need a way to "remember" the main sort order and then sort by two different criteria: one for the "overall" sort order and one for each child level:

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, name, parent_id, order_by as main_order, null::int as child_order
   from category
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id, p.main_order, c.order_by as child_order
   from category c
     join tree p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
select *
from tree 
order by main_order, child_order nulls first;
```

By carrying the `order_by` from the root level to all children, we can keep all rows that belong to the same root together. The rows for one root are then sorted according to the fake child_order - the root rows will have `null` for that column and the `nulls first` puts them at the beginning of each group.

---

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZVLII98217

Comment: That's exactly what I want to archive! Nice trick with the `child_order` column. Thanks.